# Overlapping hints and suggestions in vscode

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

Suggestions and hints are getting overlapped in vscode jupyter notebook as shown below:

[image: Screenshot]

I want autocomplete suggestions box at the bottom and the documentation related to function at the top. I don't know what to do.

Comment: It is very difficult to answer your question without seeing any of your data nor any of the code that you have written that produces your problem. Please edit your question to show a minimal reproducible set consisting of sample input, expected output, actual output, and only the relevant code necessary to reproduce the problem.  See [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example "Minimal Reproducible Example") for details on how to best help us help you.

Comment: In the screen shot i posted you can see the description of Plot method in light grey box and the suggestions are appearing at the back of it, which makes it impossible to read the suggestions. So I am asking you guys to help me change the settings of VS code such that suggestions and description of methods don't overlap on each other. Thanks for helping in advance.